# Duda número de Gaus

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estaba intentando hacer una función que devolviese números GAU en forma de string pero me di cuenta que el uno se imprime una vez en lugar de dos. Aquí hay un ejemplo de un número GAU: 11221223331223334444 ([1][122][122333][1223334444]). Este es mi código:

```
def g(n):
    a = ""    
    if n >= 1:
        a = g(n-1)    
    m = str(n)*n
    p = str(a)*2+m
    return p
```

Cuando llamamos a g(4) debería imprimir: `11221223331223334444`

En cambio al llamar a g(4) imprime: `11221223331223334444`

Lo que esta pasando es que el 1 se imprime de esta forma: `1122122333`
 cuando debería imprimirse: `11221122333`. Como verán el problema es que el número 1 aparece una vez en lugar de dos. Mi pregunta es: ¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo recomendable sería separar la función recursiva en dos, una para crear los items y otra para enlazarlos:

```
def gprime(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return gprime(n-1) + str(n)*n
```

Si comprobamos, `gprime(3) == "122333"`

Usamos esta función para construir la función que necesitamos:

```
def g(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return g(n-1) + gprime(n)
```

Con algo de experiencia en lenguajes funcionales (eg: haskell) se observa que estas funciones siguen un patrón común de *reducción* llamado `foldl` que no requiere recursividad. En Python se puede usar la función `functools.reduce` para hacer algo equivalente, pero podemos resolverlo mucho mejor usando *iteradores*:

```
def gprime(n):
    return "".join(str(i)*i for i in range(1,n+1))

def g(n):
    return "".join(gprime(i) for i in range(1,n+1))
```

Incluso con un poco de habilidad, se puede reducir los dos iteradores a uno sólo:

```
def g(n):
    return "".join(str(i)*i for j in range(1,n+1) for i in range(1,j+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está al mutliplicar `str(a)*2` en esta asignación `p = str(a)*2+m`, ya que al tratarse de una función recursiva, se está sumando cada vez todo el texto que devolvió la llamada anterior a la función, por ello se suma la parte de `1122` en vez de solamente `122`.

Como solución podrías imprimir dentro de la función en vez de multiplicar el resultado para armar la cadena y retornarla.
Con esta idea, el llamado a tu función quedaría simplemente: `g(4)` (osea sin print) y el código quedaría así:

```
def g(n):
    a = ""    
    if n >= 1:
        a = g(n-1)    
    m = str(n) * n
    p = str(a) + m
    print(p, end='')

    return p
```

Simplificando tu código, podría quedar así

```
def g(n):
    if n <= 0:
      return ''
    resultado = g(n-1) + str(n)*n 
    print(resultado, end='')
    return resultado
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada según el código que indicas en tu pregunta `g(4)` no retorna el valor que mencionas sino que devuelve: `11221122333112211223334444` que de todas formas no corresponde al valor que esperas: `11221223331223334444`, no se me ocurre, por ahora la forma de resolverlo usando recursividad, pero sí, usando un doble ciclo de la siguiente forma:

```
def g2(n):
  cadena = ""
  cadena_anterior = ""
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    cadena_anterior = ""
    for j in range(1,i):
      cadena_anterior = cadena_anterior + str(j)*j
    cadena = cadena + cadena_anterior + str(i)*i
  return cadena
```